# issue with QUALIFY RANK

Tags: sql, teradata, rank, dense-rank, teradatasql

Trying to delete records using below query.

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_1 WHERE NUMB IN 
(
SELECT NUMB FROM TABLE_2 
WHERE FLAG='Y' 
QUALIFY DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY LOAD_TIMESTAMP DESC )=1
)
```

Looks like issue with QUALIFY in sub-query. can you please advise alternate solution ?

Comment: Could you tag the RDBMS (sql server, oracle ...) you are using ?

Comment: Please also share the error message you received

Comment: You are correct, you cannot use qualify in a subquery.  However, if you wrap the subquery in a derived table,  it works.  Not saying this means your delete will work correctly, just a general comment.

Answer (score 1):

> can you please advise alternate solution ?

This query uses nesting rather than `QUALIFY`:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_1 WHERE NUMB IN 
(
  SELECT NUMB 
  FROM (
    SELECT NUMB, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY LOAD_TIMESTAMP DESC ) AS rn
    FROM TABLE_2 
    WHERE FLAG='Y'
  ) AS s
  WHERE rn = 1
)
```

Comment: This query will actually delete ?